# Pandas: Calculate the time between columns for when a condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, difference

I would like to calculate the number of days since the last breakdown(s) happened.
My table has the **Date column (Day)** in datetime format, and the **Number of breakdowns column**.

```
print (df)
          Day  Number of breakdowns
0  2017-01-09                   1.0
1  2017-01-12                   0.0
2  2017-01-13                   0.0
3  2017-01-14                   0.0
4  2017-01-16                   3.0
5  2017-01-17                   0.0
6  2017-01-18                   0.0
7  2017-01-19                   1.0
8  2017-01-20                   0.0
9  2017-01-21                   0.0
10 2017-01-23                   1.0
```

[image: Table I want]

Comment: not having the raw data, i can suggest getting indexes of breakdowns by the `.nonzero()` function, and then comparing each zero entry with most recent populated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare `Number of breakdowns` with non equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) with cumulative sum by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for transform [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) value per group, so possible subtract and convert timedeltas to [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])

s = df.groupby(df['Number of breakdowns'].ne(0).cumsum())['Day'].transform('first')
df['New'] = (df['Day'] - s).dt.days
print (df)
          Day  Number of breakdowns  New
0  2017-01-09                   1.0    0
1  2017-01-12                   0.0    3
2  2017-01-13                   0.0    4
3  2017-01-14                   0.0    5
4  2017-01-16                   3.0    0
5  2017-01-17                   0.0    1
6  2017-01-18                   0.0    2
7  2017-01-19                   1.0    0
8  2017-01-20                   0.0    1
9  2017-01-21                   0.0    2
10 2017-01-23                   1.0    0
```

Comment: Thank so much! Worked perfectly